# NodeJS - Socket.io - Android : All messages aren't received

Tags: android, node.js, socket.io

I have a NodeJs/Socket.io server.
I have a Android client, and want to create communication.

Connection works, sending messages from android client works and I get responses.

There is just sometimes answers from server that doesn't arrived to the client :

```
Android : socket.emit("setPosition",loc);
Server : socket.on('setPosition',function(loc){
   ...
   socket.emit('map',obj);
   ...
})
```

When I test the server with HTML exemple everything works, but with android, I "almost" never got the message from

```
socket.emit('map',obj);
```

I'm using this client : https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client

I couldn't find any known bug open on this, does someone has an idea ?

Edit : This is the android configuration of the socket. It's working since I receive "sometimes" the answer.

```
socket.connect(new IOCallback() {
            @Override
            public void on(String event, IOAcknowledge ack, Object... args) {
                System.out.println("" + args[0]);

                if("map".equals(event) && args.length > 0){
                    updateMap(args[0]);
                    // TODO Not working
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessage(JSONObject json, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                System.out.println("onMessage");
            }
            @Override
            public void onMessage(String data, IOAcknowledge ack) {
                System.out.println("onMessage");
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(SocketIOException socketIOException) {
                System.out.println("" + socketIOException.getCause());
            }
            @Override
            public void onDisconnect() {}
            @Override
            public void onConnect() {
                socket.emit("setToken", token);
            }
        });
```

I'd like to add also that I monitor on the server and the message is correctly sent

```
debug: xhr-polling writing 5:::{"name":"map","args":[...]}
```

Edit 2 :

I did some more testing on this issue and have some new informations :

If I make 1 socket.emit("setPosition",obj) call, I get nothing.

If I make 2 socket.emit("setPosition",obj) calls in a row, then I got every time 1 answer.

If I make n socket.emit("setPosition",obj) calls in a row, then I got every time n-1 answers.

So I'm wondering if there is an issue with the connection and if it remains open long enough when I do 1 calling to get the answer.
I also checked and the "connection" is open.

If someone has an idea :)

Thanks,
Ivan

Comment: on client side (android), do you have: public void on('map',....) method?

Comment: Yes, I add some details on the post.

Comment: in on() method, you actually have "..." before (args)? Try printing System.out.println("Event: " + event + " args len: " + args.length); and see what you're getting before doing if (event.equals("map")

Comment: For the "..." before args, it's from this exemple : https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client/blob/master/examples/basic/BasicExample.java

Comment: Also I tried with the System.out.println(...), it's wierd since I got the result just sometimes. Even if the line appears on the server side.

Comment: Oh ok, been working with javascript for too long, forgot about java's dot dot dot... :)

Comment: i have this problem as you and i don't know why